# Access client's SQL Database with PHP

Tags: php, sql, security

I was thinking is there a method to gain access to a client PC's SQL database? I am creating a web portal for our LAN clients and I will need to manipulate data on the client's database.

Comment: You'll have to fill in a lot more details here. It's very vague what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  you cannot do this with PHP.  Php runs on the server.

You cannot do this with javascript in the browser as it is not allowed access to the client pc.

You may be able to write a chrome or firefox plugin that will have access to the host pc and then write code to interact with it.

Or just write an application for your clients to install that comunicates with your app on the php server.